# Prevent AutoScroll when contained Control gets focus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `Panel` with two `Button`s on it, one of which is partially hidden. When the partially-hidden button gets focus - such as when the other is clicked and then it  (-the original) is clicked - the panel gets scrolled.
I need the vertical scrollbar but not the *auto* scrolling, and there seems to be no way of getting a functioning scrollbar without the auto scrolling.

The code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Panel panel = new Panel
        {
            AutoScroll = true,
            Size = new Size(200, 200),
            Location = new Point(0, 30),
        };
        Button b1 = new Button
        {
            Location = new Point(100, 100),
            Size = new Size(50, 150),
            BackColor = Color.Black
        };
        Button b2 = new Button();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel.Controls.Add(b1);
            Controls.Add(panel);
            Controls.Add(b2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a derived class which can access the VScroll property.

But more simply and works better:

Override `ScrollToControl`. See [How can you stop a Winforms Panel from scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419774/how-can-you-stop-a-winforms-panel-from-scrolling/912610#912610) .