# Get real-time scrolling without AutoScroll

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

After asking this: [Prevent AutoScroll when contained Control gets focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368320/prevent-autoscroll-when-contained-control-gets-focus) I've found a way to have a scrollbar without the AutoScroll (using a derived class which can access the `VScroll` property). However - it's not in real-time. i.e. Only when the user is done scrolling does the Control actually get scrolled. (as opposed to a Panel with `AutoScroll = true`.) So how do I get it to scroll in real-time?

My code:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel
        {
            //AutoScroll = true,
            Size = new Size(200, 200),
            Location = new Point(0, 30),
            BackColor = Color.Green
        };
        Button b1 = new Button
        {
            Location = new Point(100, 100),
            Size = new Size(50, 150),
            BackColor = Color.Black
        };
        Button b2 = new Button();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel.Controls.Add(b1);
            Controls.Add(panel);
            Controls.Add(b2);
            Shown += new System.EventHandler(Form1_Shown);
        }

        void Form1_Shown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            panel.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
            panel.SetV();
        }
    }

    class MyPanel : Panel
    {
        public void SetV() { VScroll = true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to override the panel's OnScroll() method and call SetDisplayRectLocation(0, -se.NewValue).  This voids the warranty.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks yet again. Works great. You can transform that into an answer. It deserves the rep.

Comment: @HansPassant `This voids the warranty.` - Do you mean that there are problems with doing this?

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment:

> You'll need to override the panel's OnScroll() method and call
>   SetDisplayRectLocation(0, -se.NewValue).

That's the answer to this question.

However, I've found that I can't have both scrollbars simultaneously. Or at least - I haven't found a way to do it.